# sum of N natural Number Using Recursion in c

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
int sum(int n);
int main()
{

    printf("sum is %d", sum(5));
    return 0;

}
//recursive function
int sum(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
   int sumNm1=sum(n-1); //sum of 1 to n
   int sumN=sumNm1+n;
}
```

Here i didn't understand how this code works when n==1 becomes true,
How this code backtracks itself afterwards..?

Comment: It "backtracks" though the call stack. But you miss the last `return sumN;` in `sum`.

Comment: you are missing a return statement at the end of your function

Comment: It does not return sumN, It should not work

Comment: Did you try compiling the current code? The compiler should throw a warning, if not an error. I suggest compiling with flags `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to be sure not to miss these kinds of simple mistakes in your code.

Comment: Simpler than all these intermediate variables is simply `return n + sum(n-1);`...

Comment: You do not handle the special case of 0 – simplest would be testing for 0 and returning 0 then just as you do for 1 now (1 itself would then just recurse another time). As you accept a signed integer: You do not handle negative input appropriately either! Now think about negative input – can it be handled meaningfully (e.g. like `if(n < 0) { return -sum(-n); }`? If you decide *'no'* then you might rather want to change to `unsigned int` instead to express the fact.

Comment: Yet a potential problem: For large input values your sum variable might overflow (UB in case of signed integer, not so for unsigned, but the result would still get invalid). As the closed formula `n*(n+1)/2` reveals you can avoid by choosing a result value of twice the size your input, you might then opt for fixed-size integers, e.g. `uint64_t sum(uint32_t n);` (need to `#include <stdint.h>` for).

Comment: @SanPei: There is no “should not work” with undefined behavior. “Undefined behavior” means the C standard does not impose any requirements. That is **any** requirements; it does not say it should work, and it does not say it should not work.

Comment: Assume you have two functions `f` and `g`. Assume the function `f` calls `g` to calculate its own result. You will notice that `f` cannot complete until `g` has done so, e.g. `int g(int n) { return n + 1; } int f(int n) { return 1 + g(n); }`: Obviously `f` cannot complete until `g` has incremented its argument and returned to `f`. The same applies for recursive calls: `sum(3)` cannot complete until `sum(2)` has done so, which again needs to wait for `sum(1)`. And for not overwriting its own argument each function call stores its own value of `n` on the stack before recursing.

Answer (score 1):

The code needs a `return` statement in the case where `n` is not 1:

```
int sum(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int sumNm1=sum(n-1); //sum of 1 to n
    int sumN=sumNm1+n;
    return sumN;
}
```

or more simply:

```
int sum(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return n + sum(n-1);
}
```

> How this code backtracks itself afterwards..?

When a function is called, the program saves information about hwo to get back to the calling context. When `return` statement is executed, the program uses the saved information to return to the calling context.

This is usually implemented via a hardware stack, a region of memory set aside for this purpose. There is a stack pointer that points to the active portion of the stack memory. When `main` calls `sum(5)`, a return address into `main` is pushed onto the stack, and the stack pointer is adjusted to point to memory that is then used for the local variables in `sum`. When `sum` calls `sum(n-1)`, which is `sum(4)`, a return address into `sum` is pushed onto the stack, and the stack pointer is adjusted again. This continues for `sum(3)`, `sum(2)`, and `sum(1)`. For `sum(1)`, the function returns 1, and the saved return address is used to go back to the previous execution of `sum`, for `sum(2)`, and the stack pointer is adjusted in the reverse direction. Then the returned value 1 is added to its `n`, and 3 is returned. The saved address is used to go back to the previous execution, and the stack pointer is again adjusted in the reverse direction. This continues until the original `sum(5)` is executing again. It returns 15 and uses the saved address to go back to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

If this program were implemented correctly, it would work like this: When n is 1, the function returns 1. When n is 2, the function calls itself for n is 1, so it gets 1, and then adds n (i.e., 2) to it. When n is 3, the function calls itself for n is 2, so it gets 3, and then adds n (i.e., 3) to it. And so on.

Comment: It won't for anything larger than 1!!! In these cases the function doesn't return a value, and as the functions return value is evaluated the programme yields undefined behaviour! You need to hint to this problem to make this answer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Like pointed in comments, the problem is that you **don't return the value** you compute from within the function (***U**ndefined **B**ehavior*). You calculate it correctly (but in a clumsy way, using 2 unneeded variables).
**If you add a `return sumN;` statement at the end of the function, things should be fine.**

Also, the type chosen for the return value is not the best one. You should choose:

- An unsigned type (as we are talking about natural numbers), otherwise half of its interval would be simply wasted (on negative values - which won't be used)
- One that's as large as possible (*uint64_t*). Note that this only allows larger values to be computed, but does not eliminate the possibility of an overflow, so you should also be careful when choosing the input type (*uint32_t*)

More details on recursion: [[Wikipedia]: Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) (it also contains an example very close to yours: *factorial*).

I've prepared an example.

*main00.c*:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define PC064U_FMT "%llu"
#  define PC064UX_FMT "0x%016llX"
#else
#  define PC064U_FMT "%lu"
#  define PC064UX_FMT "0x%016lX"
#endif


uint64_t sum(uint32_t n)  // Just 3 lines of code
{
    if (n < 2)
        return n;
    return n + sum(n - 1);
}


uint64_t sum_gauss(uint32_t n)
{
    if (n == (uint32_t)-1)
        return (uint64_t)(n - 1) / 2 * n + n;
    return n % 2 ? (uint64_t)(n + 1) / 2 * n : (uint64_t)n / 2 * (n + 1);
}


uint64_t sum_acc(uint32_t n, uint64_t acc)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return acc;
    return sum_acc(n - 1, acc + n);
}


int main()
{
    uint32_t numbers[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 254, 255, 1000, 100000, (uint32_t)-2, (uint32_t)-1 };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]); ++i) {
        uint64_t res = sum_gauss(numbers[i]);
        printf("\nsum_gauss(%u): "PC064U_FMT" ("PC064UX_FMT")\n", numbers[i], res, res);
        res = sum_acc(numbers[i], 0);
        printf("  sum_acc(%u): "PC064U_FMT" ("PC064UX_FMT")\n", numbers[i], res, res);
        res = sum(numbers[i]);
        printf("      sum(%u): "PC064U_FMT" ("PC064UX_FMT")\n", numbers[i], res, res);
    }
    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Notes**:

- I added Gauss's formula (*sum_gauss*) to calculate the same thing using just simple arithmetic operations (and thus is waaay faster)
- Another thing about recursion: although it's a nice technique (very useful for learning), it's not so practical (because each function call eats up stack), and if function calls itself many times, the stack will eventually run out (*StackOverflow*). A recurrent call can be worked around that using an optimization - with the help of an accumulator (check [[Wikipedia]: Tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) or [[SO]: What is tail call optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310974/4788546)). I added *sum_acc* to illustrate this
- Didn't consider necessary to also add the iterative variant (as it would only be a simple *for* loop)

**Output**:

> ```
> (qaic-env) [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q074798666]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> main00.c  vs2022
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -O2 -o exe main00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ./exe
>
> sum_gauss(0): 0 (0x0000000000000000)
>   sum_acc(0): 0 (0x0000000000000000)
>       sum(0): 0 (0x0000000000000000)
>
> sum_gauss(1): 1 (0x0000000000000001)
>   sum_acc(1): 1 (0x0000000000000001)
>       sum(1): 1 (0x0000000000000001)
>
> sum_gauss(2): 3 (0x0000000000000003)
>   sum_acc(2): 3 (0x0000000000000003)
>       sum(2): 3 (0x0000000000000003)
>
> sum_gauss(3): 6 (0x0000000000000006)
>   sum_acc(3): 6 (0x0000000000000006)
>       sum(3): 6 (0x0000000000000006)
>
> sum_gauss(5): 15 (0x000000000000000F)
>   sum_acc(5): 15 (0x000000000000000F)
>       sum(5): 15 (0x000000000000000F)
>
> sum_gauss(10): 55 (0x0000000000000037)
>   sum_acc(10): 55 (0x0000000000000037)
>       sum(10): 55 (0x0000000000000037)
>
> sum_gauss(254): 32385 (0x0000000000007E81)
>   sum_acc(254): 32385 (0x0000000000007E81)
>       sum(254): 32385 (0x0000000000007E81)
>
> sum_gauss(255): 32640 (0x0000000000007F80)
>   sum_acc(255): 32640 (0x0000000000007F80)
>       sum(255): 32640 (0x0000000000007F80)
>
> sum_gauss(1000): 500500 (0x000000000007A314)
>   sum_acc(1000): 500500 (0x000000000007A314)
>       sum(1000): 500500 (0x000000000007A314)
>
> sum_gauss(100000): 5000050000 (0x000000012A06B550)
>   sum_acc(100000): 5000050000 (0x000000012A06B550)
>       sum(100000): 5000050000 (0x000000012A06B550)
>
> sum_gauss(4294967294): 9223372030412324865 (0x7FFFFFFE80000001)
>   sum_acc(4294967294): 9223372030412324865 (0x7FFFFFFE80000001)
>       sum(4294967294): 9223372030412324865 (0x7FFFFFFE80000001)
>
> sum_gauss(4294967295): 9223372034707292160 (0x7FFFFFFF80000000)
>   sum_acc(4294967295): 9223372034707292160 (0x7FFFFFFF80000000)
>       sum(4294967295): 9223372034707292160 (0x7FFFFFFF80000000)
>
> Done.
> ```

[image: Img0]

As seen in the image above, the simple implementation (*sum*) failed while the other 2 passed (for a certain (big) input value). Not sure though why it didn't also fail on *Linux* (*WSL*), most likely one of the optimizations (from *-O2*) enabled *tail-end-recursion* (or increased the stack?).

Comment: Both of you're variants don't protect from overflow! Someone might try to calculate e.g. `sum(1ull << 33)`. `uint32_t` as input parameter would only allow values for which the sum *can* be calculated, though the Gaussian variant, as is, would still overflow for maximum value of uint32_t 0xffffffff (but only for this one).

Comment: @Aconcagua: thank you, I missed the input parameter part!!! Now it shouldn't overflow (`0xffffffff * (0xffffffff + 1) / 2 < 0xffffffffffffffff`, hmmm although *0x100000000* is outside *uint32\_t* bounds so it would probably be 0).

Comment: Indeed, you need to cast `n` *before* adding 1 already...

Comment: Important to consider, too, is that the product must not overflow either *before* being devided by 2! This won't be the case, though, `0xffff * 0x10000` calculates to `0xffff0000` (dropped some digits, but that's analogous...).

Answer (score 0):

> How this code backtracks itself afterwards..?

It doesn't certainly work.

Any success is due to *undefined behavior* (UB).

The biggest mistake is not compiling with a well enabled compiler.

```
int sum(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
   int sumNm1=sum(n-1); //sum of 1 to n 
   int sumN=sumNm1+n;                   // !! What, no warning?
}                                       // !! What, no warning?
```

A well enabled compiler generates warnings something like the below.

```
warning: unused variable 'sumN' [-Wunused-variable]
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

**Save time** and enable all compiler warnings. You get faster feedback to code troubles than posting on SO.

```
   int sumN=sumNm1+n;
   return sumN;  // Add
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're more interested in how recursion actually works, than in the error produced by the missing return statement (see any of the other answers).

So here's my personal guide to understanding recurive functions.

If you know about [Mathematical Induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction), this might help understand how recursion works (a least it did for me). You prove a base case(, make an assumption about a fixed value) and prove the statement for a following number. In programming we do a very similar thing.

Firstly, identify your base cases, i.e. some input to the function that you *know* what the output is. In your example this is

```
if(n==1)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Now, we need to find a way to compute the value for any given input from "smaller" inputs; in this case `sum(n) = sum(n-1) +n`.

**How does backtracking work after the base case has been reached?**

To understand this, picture the function call `sum(2)`.
We first find that 2 does not match our base case, so we recursively call the function with `sum(2-1)`. You can imagine this recursive call as the function called with `sum(2)` halting until `sum(1)` has returned a result. Now `sum(1)` is the "active" function, and we find that it matches our base case, so we return 1. This is now returned to where `sum(2)` has waited for the result, and this function now can compute `2 + sum(1)`, because we got the result from the recursive call.
This goes on like this for every recursive call, that is made.

Interested in a bit more low-level explanation?

In assembly (MIPS), your code would look something like this:

```
sum:
addi $t1, $0, 1     # store '1' in $t0
beq $a0, $t0, base  # IF n == 1: GOTO base
                    # ELSE:
                    # prepare for recursive call:
sw $a0, 4($sp)      #   write n on top of the stack
sw %ra, 8($sp)      #   write the line of the caller on top of stack
addi $sp, $sp, 8    #   advance stack pointer
addi $a0, $a0, -1   #   n = n-1
jal sum             #   call sum with reduced n
                    # this is executed AFTER the recursive call
addi $sp, $sp, -8   #   reset stack pointer
lw %ra, 8($sp)      #   load where to exit the function
lw %a0, 4($sp)      #   load the original n this instance of sum got
add %v0, %a0, %v0   #   add our n to the result of sum(n-1)
jr %ra              #   return to wherever sum() was called
base:               # this is only executed when base case is reached
add %v0, %0, %t1    #   write '1' as return statement of base case
jr %ra              #   reutrn to caller
```

Anytime the recursive function is called, we temporarily store the argument the current function got (`$a0`) and the calling function (`$ra`) on the stack. That's basically a LIFO storage, and we can access the top of it using the stack pointer `$sp`. So when we enter recursion, we want to make room on the stack for whatever we need to store there by advancing the stack pointer(`addi $sp, $sp, 8`); we can now store whatever we need there.

When this is done, we manipulate the argument we got (function arguments are always stored in `$a0` in MIPS so we need to overwrite the argument we got). We write `n-1` as argument for our recursive call and proceed to 'jump and lin' (jal) to the beginning of the function. This jumps to the provided label (start of our function) and saves the current line of code in `$ra` so we can return here after the function call. For every recursive call we make, the stack grows, because we store our data there, so we need to remember to reset it lateron.

Once a function call gets the argument 1, the programm jumps to `base`, we can simply write 1 into the designated return register (`$v0`), and jump back to the line of code we were called from.

This is the line where we used jal to jump back to the beginning. Since the called function provided the result of the base case in `$v0`,we can simply add our argument to `$v0`and return. However we first need to recover the argument and the return address from the stack. We also decrement the stack pointer, so that it is in the exact position where it was when the function was called. Therefore all recursive calls work together to compute the overall result; every idividual call has it's own storage on the stack, but it also ensures to tidy up before exiting, so that all the other calls can access their respective data.

The takeaway is: When calling a function recursively, execution jumps back to the beginning of the function with altered arguments. However, every individual function call handles their own set of variables (temporarily store on the stack). After a recursive call returns a value, the next most-inner recursive call becomes active, re-loads all their variables and computes the next result.